# Moving a directory from a user to another user, keeping the correct permissions

Tags: linux, bash, permissions, users

Let's suppose we have to users: `alice` and `bob`.

Now Bob wants to move Alice's `~/Documents` directory into his home folder.

What's the best workflow to do that, updating the permissions (from Alice to Bob)?

That means that all the rights Alice has on the `/home/alice/Documents/` (directories and files, recursively) to be added to Bob `/home/bob/Documents/` (directories and files, recursively), and Alice's rights will be removed from `/home/bob/Documents`.

Comment: Can you update your question with your interpretation of what are correct permissions? You only talk about ownership in the body of your post.

Comment: @Anthon I just want to migrate Alice's files to Bob. So, probably only the ownership is the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you change the file owner using `chown`, the permissions for alice would be transferred to bob. So here's the flow:

```
sudo mv ~bob/Documents ~bob/Documents.orig
sudo mv ~alice/Documents/ ~bob/Documents
sudo chown -PR bob ~bob/Documents
```

**Edit:**

In case you want to overwrite the group as well, use

```
sudo chown -PR bob:bob ~bob/Documents
```

Or:

```
sudo chown -PR bob: ~bob/Documents
```

to use bob's primary group.

However, beware that this could be problematic in case `~alice/Documents` had non-default group permissions. In that case it might be better to use something like

```
sudo find ~bob/Documents -group alice -exec chown -h bob: {} +
```

If ACLs are in use, you may want to check those as well.

Answer (score 5):

As Bob:

```
mv ~bob/Documents ~bob/Documents.orig
cp --remove-destination --no-preserve=ownership -r ~alice/Documents/ ~bob/
sudo rm -fr ~alice/Documents/
```

Comment: I accepted the other answer, but this looks good too. I voted it and other answers posted by you. :-) Thanks!

Comment: @Costas: Is there an advantage of using cp vs mv ? The latter only adjust pointers to the filesystem and is much faster if both home folders are on the same filesystem. Or did I miss something ?

Comment: @Karolos Yes, you are right. But the main advantage of `cp` have much more options. Thus if we told about files on same filesystem you can use option `-l(--link)` to make just hard-links instead of copying.

Comment: @Costas I see; good point about the options, and `-l` is a good option to provide indeed.

Comment: @Karolos Another point would be that I probably want to delete Alice's documents after one week. :-) So, I used `cp` instead of `mv`.

Answer (score 2):

```
cp -avv /home/alice/Documents/ /home/bob/newDocuments/ && 
  chown -Rvv bob:bob /home/bob/newDocuments/
```

Comment: +1 for considering the group as well (:bob)

Answer (score 1):

If bob has no permission to read alice's home folder you should do some operations as super user (if Bob has no already that power)
I personally will use something like this:

```
sudo rsync -a --progress /home/alice/Documents/ /home/bob/Documents/
sudo chown -Rv bob:bob_group /home/bob/Documents
sudo rm -rv /home/alice/Documents
```

- rsync is very versatile you may chose what files you want to skip or sync an already existing folder or copy from a remote host and more other options. I this example "-a" stands for archive. It implies more rsync options like -r and -p which stands for recursive and preserve permission. It include also -o (preserve owner) and -g (preserve group) and you can tweak this options as you prefer. So at the end of execution of this command you will have a clone an Alice's Documents folder in Bob's home folder.
- chown will change owner and owner group of new folder
- rm, will remove original folder if you want that.